# Scalar multiple sequence converges to scalar multiple?

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-analysis

Let $\mathbf{x}_i \to \mathbf{x} \neq 0$ be a convergent sequence in $\mathbb{R}^n$.  Suppose $r_i$ is a sequence of real numbers which may or may not converge, but we are given that $r_i\mathbf{x}_i$ *does* converge to some $\mathbf{y} \in \mathbb{R}^n$.

Is $\mathbf{y}$ necessarily a scalar multiple of $\mathbf{x}$? I'm almost sure of this, but can't figure out how to prove it.

I'm thinking that the components of $r_i \mathbf{x}_i$ perpendicular to $\mathbf{x}_i$ are zero, so the component of $\mathbf{y}$ perpendicular to $\mathbf{x}$ must also be zero, but I'm not sure how to formally prove this.

Answer (score 0):

No.

For example, imagine $\mathbf{x}_i$ is in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{x}_i = \frac{1}{5i+1}$ and $r_i = 10i$ then $y_i \cdot \mathbf{x}_i \to \mathbf{2}$ which is not a multiple of $0$. Also, $r_i \ne \alpha.\mathbf{x}_i$ for any $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: Sorry, you're right, but I've had to revise my question; I'm interested in the case where $\textbf{x} \neq 0$.

Comment: In that case, if $r_i$ converges your conclusion is correct. But, if $x_i \to x \ne 0$ then $r_i \cdot x_i$ won't converge if $r_i$ doesn't converge - it either diverges or oscillates.

Comment: Yes, suppose $r_i x_i$ converges. Any idea how to prove it converges to a scalar multiple?

Comment: Hint: $\mathbf{x}_i \in \mathbb{R}^N$ converges if and only if all its components are convergent sequences. This becomes like proving the same thing/theorem for $N$ independent sequences.